# hive sql query get last week, month, in one query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the following hive sql query

I would like to use the same query to get the

- last week of data
- last month
- last three months

Ideally I would like it done in one query. Is that possible

```
SELECT
'global_authenticated' AS experiment_type,
--experiment data
experiment_name,
variant_name,
MIN(first_date) AS min_date,
COUNT(DISTINCT visid)
FROM dwo_analysis.spark_global_authenticated_experiment_dashboard_report_activity c    
GROUP BY experiment_name, variant_name;
```

Comment: sample data and the expected output would help answer this.

Comment: You should tell us what you want to see in the output. Do you want `MIN(first_date)` and  `COUNT(DISTINCT visid)` for all three criteria, whether last month / three months imply 30 days / 90 days or start of calendar month from current month etc. Clearly mention all these giving examples of the output with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read from the table three times, label each set of read data as either "last_week", "last_month" and "last_3_months", then `UNION ALL` the three data sets. See:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'global_authenticated' AS experiment_type
        ,
        --experiment data
        experiment_name
        ,variant_name
        ,MIN(first_date) AS min_date
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT visid)
        ,"last week" AS date_extract
    FROM dwo_analysis.spark_global_authenticated_experiment_dashboard_report_activity c
    WHERE DATE < "the last week"
    GROUP BY experiment_name
        ,variant_name

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'global_authenticated' AS experiment_type
        ,
        --experiment data
        experiment_name
        ,variant_name
        ,MIN(first_date) AS min_date
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT visid)
        ,"last month" AS date_extract
    FROM dwo_analysis.spark_global_authenticated_experiment_dashboard_report_activity c
    WHERE DATE < "the last month"
    GROUP BY experiment_name
        ,variant_name
    ) first_union

UNION ALL

SELECT 'global_authenticated' AS experiment_type
    ,
    --experiment data
    experiment_name
    ,variant_name
    ,MIN(first_date) AS min_date
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT visid)
    ,"last 3 months" AS date_extract
FROM dwo_analysis.spark_global_authenticated_experiment_dashboard_report_activity c
WHERE DATE < "the last 3 months"
GROUP BY experiment_name
    ,variant_name
```